# Sklearn GridSearch with PredefinedSplit scoring does not match a standalone classifier

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn, grid-search, scoring

I am using sklearn GridSearch to find best parameters for random forest classification using a predefined validation set. The scores from the best estimator returned by GridSearch do not match the scores obtained by training a separate classifier with the same parameters.

The data split definition

```
X = pd.concat([X_train, X_devel])
y = pd.concat([y_train, y_devel])
test_fold = -X.index.str.contains('train').astype(int)
ps = PredefinedSplit(test_fold)
```

The GridSearch definition

```
n_estimators = [10]
max_depth = [4]
grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators, 'max_depth': max_depth}

rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
rf_grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_grid = grid, cv = ps, scoring='recall_macro')
rf_grid.fit(X, y)
```

The classifier definition

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, max_depth=4, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The recall was calculated explicitly using sklearn.metrics.recall_score

```
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X_train)
y_pred_devel = clf.predict(X_devel)

uar_train = recall_score(y_train, y_pred_train, average='macro')
uar_devel = recall_score(y_devel, y_pred_devel, average='macro')
```

GridSearch

```
uar train:  0.32189884516029466
uar devel:  0.3328299259976279
```

Random Forest:

```
uar train:  0.483040291148839
uar devel:  0.40706644557392435
```

What is the reason for such a mismatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

1. Your input arguments to `recall_score` are reversed. The actual correct order is:

   ```
   recall_score(y_true, y_test)
   ```

   But you are are doing:

   ```
   recall_score(y_pred_train, y_train, average='macro')
   ```

   Correct that to:

   ```
   recall_score(y_train, y_pred_train, average='macro')
   ```
2. You are doing `rf_grid.fit(X, y)` for grid-search. That means that after finding the best parameter combinations, the GridSearchCV will fit the whole data (whole X, ignoring the `PredefinedSplit` because that's only used during cross-validation in search of best parameters). So in essence, the estimator from `GridSearchCV` will have seen the whole data, so scores will be different from what you get when you do `clf.fit(X_train, y_train)`

Comment: Thanks for the insights. Something still unclear after changing the order of the arguments, the recall after retraining on the whole dataset is expected to improve (since the classifier have now seen all the data), however it remains lower for both train and devel subsets. Any clues why is that?

Comment: @OxanaVerkholyak I'm sorry I cannot say anything more without seeing the data samples. There can be many things: 1) Is your train-test split balanced? 2) Is your data imbalanced? 3) How many classes are there?. "recall_macro" does not take label imbalance into account. Maybe that could be reason. What about other metrics, accuracy, confusion matrix etc. Please post the complete code along with some sample data which may produce this result.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your `GridSearchCV` you are using the scoring function as `recall-macro` which basically return the `recall score` which is `macro` averaged. See [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values).

However, when you are returning the default score from your `RandomForestClassifier` it returns the `mean accuracy`. So, that is why the scores are different. See [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score) for info on the same. (Since one is recall and the other is accuracy).